# Determining whether the extremal problem has a weak minimum or strong minimum or both

Tags: calculus-of-variations, integral-equations

The extremal of the functional $\int_{0}^{\alpha}{\left((y')^2 - y^2\right)dx}$ that passes through (0,0) and (${\alpha}$,0) has a

1. weak minimum if ${\alpha}$ < $\pi$
2. strong minimum if ${\alpha}$ < $\pi$
3. weak minimum if ${\alpha}$ > $\pi$
4. strong minimum if ${\alpha}$ > $\pi$

Comparing the given functional to the standard form

$J = \int_{a}^{b} F(x, y, y^{'})$,

we have $F(x, y, y^{'}) = {\left((y')^2 - y^2\right)}$

and the Euler equation implies
that the extremals must satisfy the differential equation 
$y{''} + y = 0$

Thus, the extremals are given by $y(x)=A\cos(x+\delta_1)+B\sin(x+\delta_2)$.

The boundary condition y(0) = 0 implies A = 0 and $y({\alpha}) = 0$ implies ${\alpha} + {\delta_2} = n{\pi}$ , where n is an integer.

Now , $F_{y'y'}=2>0$ so the function achieves strong minimum.

I am confused how the bound on ${\alpha}$ has to be used.

The correct options are 1 & 2. This question appeared in CSIR Net Exam June 2015.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also add a phase to your solutions, i.e the general solution is actually
$$y(x)=A\cos(x+\delta_1)+B\sin(x+\delta_2)$$